How to prevent BIN attack on a Laravel v11 Livewire-based checkout system?
I am currently facing a BIN attack on the checkout page of my web application, which is built using Laravel and Livewire. Fraudulent users (or bots) are attempting to perform card testing by using a series of invalid or stolen credit card numbers with similar BINs (Bank Identification Numbers). These repeated attempts are affecting my payment gateway and creating issues with legitimate transactions.
I want to implement a solution that will prevent these attacks by adding additional security layers to my checkout process.
Here's what I've done so far:

I am using Laravel Livewire to handle form submissions for the checkout process.

Payments are processed using a third-party payment gateway(Stripe).

I have basic validation in place for form inputs, but this doesn't seem to prevent the BIN attack.


I am looking for recommendations on how to prevent these attacks effectively.
Specifically, I want to:

Detect and block bots or malicious users performing rapid multiple transactions with invalid card details.
Rate-limit requests or add CAPTCHA where appropriate.
Implement better protection strategies like logging suspicious activities or blocking repeated failed transactions from the same IP address

this is what i used in livewire function:
     public function initializePayment()
        {
          $application = Application::findOrFail($this->applicationId);
    
           $stripe = new StripeClient(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));

    // Define line items for the Stripe session
    $lineItem = [
        [
            'price_data' => [
                'currency' => 'usd',
                'product_data' => [
                    'name' => 'Test Name', // Set the product name
                    'description' => "Description", // Set the product description
                    'images' => [asset('assets/images/1.jpeg')], // Add image URL
                ],
                'unit_amount' => 49 * 100, // Amount in cents
            ],
            'quantity' => 1,
        ],
    ];

    // Create a Stripe checkout session
    $stripeSession = $stripe->checkout->sessions->create([
        'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
        'line_items' => $lineItem,
        'mode' => 'payment',
        'metadata' => [
            'application_id' => $application->id,
            'application_number' => $application->application_number,
        ],
        'customer_email' => $this->email, // Optional: Prefill customer's email in the 
            payment form
        'payment_intent_data' => [
            'description' => "Payment for Application #{$application- 
               >application_number}",
            'metadata' => [
                'application_id' => $application->id,
                'application_number' => $application->application_number,
                'email' => $this->email,
                'phone' => $this->phone_number,
                'first_name' => $this->first_name,
                'last_name' => $this->last_name,
               ],
             ],
            'success_url' => route('stripe.success', [], true) . '?session_id= 
              {CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
            'cancel_url' => route('stripe.cancel', [], true) . '?session_id= 
            {CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
          ]);

         // redirect to stripe gateway
       return redirect()->away($stripeSession->url);
     }


Your payment gateway should handle it, not your application. While rate limiting and spam prevention are not exclusive to "BIN" attacks and common for any application.

if the bots arnt advanced there is a real easy quik fix so the requests will be less. that is by adding an hidden checkbox and if this checkbox is checked then the request should be blocked. this works because most bots wil try to fill in everything and check everything. normal users cant check this checkbox because its hidden. this is only a quik easy fix i advice you to replace this checkbox method soon with an CAPTCHA

It's easy for the bot to capture the request from submitting the form, so rather than filling out the form, they just send the request again and again.

@oelimoe, Already tried to implemented this method, but it didn't work. Bots are able  to make thousands of transactions of $1 in few seconds.
